# determine what changed the mapping of system command like dd - vim

Tags: windows-7, vim, syntax

This morning something, I suspect a function call, changed the mappings or actions for system commands like `dd` , `e` , `j` etc. `dd` moved horizontally, 'e' moved down a line and `j` and `k` moved horizontally rather than vertically as well.

I was editing a help file and had called a function to create begin and end folds, basically concatenating `===== BEGIN` with register `"` and `====={{{` into register `z` and the end fold marker into register `x` . Used this many times in help files so not sure what went wrong closing and re-opening the file reverted to normal operation even using the function call again.

This happens at irregular intervals in other scenarios as well. I'm using Gvim 7.4 on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Is there a way to either see what changed the command or what say `dd` is mapped to currently? Also which of the `*.vim` files in the `$VIMRUNTIME/` folders should I source to revert to normal mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have some mappings overriding the default keystrokes.  If you use the `:verbose` command you can see what set a mapping (or option, or a number of other things). For example:

```
:verbose :map d
```

That should show you all mappings that start with `d` and what set the mapping.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'd somehow pasted some remaps outside the function definition.